# Move incoming email to folders with RegEx in a rule

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to use a regular expression to filter incoming messages by looking at the subject line and if it contains 6 consecutive digits, move it to a particular folder.

I found a script online which I have been trying to modify.

I want to place these emails in a folder called '`AMEX`' which is a `subfolder` of the main Inbox.

```
Sub filter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim MailDest As Outlook.Folder

    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    Reg1.Global = True
    Reg1.Pattern = "([\d][\d][\d][\d][\d][\d])"
    If Reg1.Test(Item.Subject) Then
        Set MailDest = ns.Folders("Inbox").Folders("AMEX")
        Item.Move MailDest
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the regex seems fine, do you get any errors? or its just not moving the emails to the desired folder?

Comment: There are no errors thrown at all but the mail just stays in the inbox when i rerun the rule that executes the script and moves no where.

Comment: the rule is based on new emails coming in? or existing emails? did you try to send an email to that account with 6 digits in the subject?

Comment: Yes, the rule should be based on new mails coming in. I also have tried to send an email to that account with 6 digits in the subject and it just comes through and sits in the inbox still. No errors thrown.

Comment: Does the code actually run when a new mail comes in?

Comment: ok, so now lets rule out one more thing, have you setup the rule properly? Create rule, on select action choose run a script > click on the script select the script choose ok make sure turn on this rule is checked.

Comment: There is a rule which is set to trigger the script. Aside from that, how can I tell if it attempted to run or not?

Comment: add a snippet on the first line MsgBox "Hi just got into the script" and send a new email with 6 digits look if you get the msgbox.

Comment: Yes I get the Msgbox text displaying when the rule is run so at least we know it is talking to the script.

Comment: Looks like your Regex is set to detect a Subject Line that ONLY contains six consecutive digits. To detect six consecutive digits within a longer Subject Line, use the Regex code "\b\d{6}\b". Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your reg ex but that does nto work either im afriad. Same results as last time. Msgbox is being displayed but the email does not move folder

Comment: ok, i think i got the problem, how many accounts do you have in your outlook?

Comment: Just the one single one :) The account is on an Exchange server so not sure if that may make any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is with the folder name
replace Set MailDest = ns.Folders("Inbox").Folders("AMEX")

with this line

```
Set MailDest = ns.Folders("enteryouraccountname@yourhost.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("AMEX")
```

and dont forget to put in your account name

Comment: You sir, I own a nice cold beer to. Worked like a charm, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also set it like this.

```
Set MailDest = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("AMEX")
```

[GetDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220100(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Nice and clean solution  :)