# How to Automatically Move an Email to a Folder if it Contains 10 digits in the subject line

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I would like to make it so if an email comes in with a phone number in the subject line (so 10 numerical digits) then the system automatically moves it to a folder called "Texting."

User Reidacus asked a very similar question here:
[Move incoming mail to folders with RegEx in a rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152007/move-incoming-mail-to-folders-with-regex-in-a-rule)

But I can't get it to work for me. When the email comes in it just sits in my inbox. I am very new the VBA and (sorry), I don't have a clue what I'm doing. Do I need to install anything special into my system to get this to work?

Here is my adapted code (note: in the real code I have my real email address)

```
Sub filter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim MailDest As Outlook.Folder
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    Reg1.Global = True
    Reg1.Pattern = "([\d][\d][\d][\d][\d][\d][\d][\d][\d][\d])"
    If Reg1.Test(Item.Subject) Then
        Set MailDest = ns.Folders("firstname.lastname@email.ca").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Texting")
        Item.Move MailDest
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What you mean not working, are getting any Errors?

Comment: Did you follow any of the tests done in the linked question - i.e. put a `MsgBox` in to ensure that the script is being called?

Comment: Since you are very new to VBA you may not be aware you call this with the "Run a script" option in a rule.

Comment: @Cynthea Cotmen  have you tested my code ? any feedbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for your `Sub Filter` to run everytime a new emails comes in, you need to add an **"event listener"**, by adding the code below to the ***ThisOutlookSession*** module (this code is taken from home, here on SO : [How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook) )

In order for this code to take affect, **you must Restart Outlook**.

***ThisOutlookSession* Module Code**

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' get default local Inbox
Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub


Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item

    ' Call your custom-made Filter Sub
    Call filterNewMail_TenDig(item)
End If

ProgramExit:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

Resume ProgramExit

End Sub
```

Now, you only need to make the following modifications to your Module code. Using `ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` will get you the default "Inbox" folder for the current profile (read here at [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220100(v=office.11).aspx) ).

**Sub *filterNewMail_TenDig* Code**

```
Sub filterNewMail_TenDig(item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim MailDest As Outlook.Folder

    Set ns = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With reg1
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\d{10,10}" ' Match any set of 10 digits
    End With

    If reg1.Test(item.Subject) Then
        Set MailDest = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Texting")
        item.Move MailDest
    End If

End Sub
```